# NUnit Test case creation

Tags: c#, nunit

I have  Created testsuits like following.

```
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
[TestCase(m,n,o)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
    Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

I have pass the variables m = 10, n = 2 and o = 5.

But the second test case is not accessible. it throws the following error:

> "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof
> expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
> type"

How to pass the variables name instead of values in test case?

Comment: What are m, n, and o? Constants or fields?

Comment: Have you considered [data driven tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036840/data-driven-testing-in-nunit)?

Comment: Take a look at the `TestCase` attribute [documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6.4). It only takes constants as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass variables to a test case unless they are constants.

Answer (score 0):

As nickmkk mentioned the variable has to be constant.

You do not need to pass the second attribute if you do not need to. In case you do, you pass same types in the test and in [attribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5).  It will read the parameter sequentially.

```
[TestCase(12, 4, 3)]
[TestCase(10, 5, 1)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Console.WriteLine("n={0}, d={1}, q={2}", n, d, q);
  Assert.AreEqual(q, n / d);
}
```

> **print**
>
> 1st run:   Expected: 1
>     But was:  2
>
> at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
>      at NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(Int32 expected, Int32 actual)
>      at Test.Test.DivideTest(Int32 n, Int32 d, Int32 q) in ImplicitVsExplicitTest.cs: line 22
>   n=10, d=5, q=1
>
> 2nd run
>   n=12, d=4, q=3